# How to determine the socket connection up time on Linux

Tags: linux, sockets

I can verify that the connection is up:

```
$ netstat -tn | grep "192.168.2.110"
tcp  0  0 192.168.2.100:10444  192.168.2.110:52639  ESTABLISHED
```

is there a way to check how long this tcp port connection was up (connected)?

(No, I don't have access to app logs)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. get the PID (say `$pid`) of the program by adding the `-p` option to `netstat`.
2. identify the proper line in the `/proc/net/tcp` file by looking at the `local_address` and/or `rem_address` fields (note that they are in hex format, specifically the IP address is expressed in little-endian byte order), also make sure that the `st` is `01` (for [`ESTABLISHED`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/net/tcp_states.h?id=HEAD#n17));
3. note the associated `inode` field (say `$inode`);
4. search for that `inode` among the file descriptors in `/proc/$pid/fd` and finally query the file access time of the symbolic link:

   ```
   find /proc/$pid/fd -lname "socket:\[$inode\]" -printf %t
   ```

---

That is a grunt work... here's a script (stub) to automatize the above points, it requires the remote address and it prints the *socket uptime* in seconds:

```
function suptime() {
    local addr=${1:?Specify the remote IPv4 address}
    local port=${2:?Specify the remote port number}
    # convert the provided address to hex format
    local hex_addr=$(python -c "import socket, struct; print(hex(struct.unpack('<L', socket.inet_aton('$addr'))[0])[2:10].upper().zfill(8))")
    local hex_port=$(python -c "print(hex($port)[2:].upper().zfill(4))")
    # get the PID of the owner process
    local pid=$(netstat -ntp 2>/dev/null | awk '$6 == "ESTABLISHED" && $5 == "'$addr:$port'"{sub("/.*", "", $7); print $7}')
    [ -z "$pid" ] && { echo 'Address does not match' 2>&1; return 1; }
    # get the inode of the socket
    local inode=$(awk '$4 == "01" && $3 == "'$hex_addr:$hex_port'" {print $10}' /proc/net/tcp)
    [ -z "$inode" ] && { echo 'Cannot lookup the socket' 2>&1; return 1; }
    # query the inode status change time
    local timestamp=$(find /proc/$pid/fd -lname "socket:\[$inode\]" -printf %T@)
    [ -z "$timestamp" ] && { echo 'Cannot fetch the timestamp' 2>&1; return 1; }
    # compute the time difference
    LANG=C printf '%s (%.2fs ago)\n' "$(date -d @$timestamp)" $(bc <<<"$(date +%s.%N) - $timestamp")
}
```

*(Edit thanks to [Alex](https://superuser.com/users/486226/alex-vazquez-fente) for the [fixes](https://superuser.com/a/960189/46005))*

Example:

```
$ suptime 93.184.216.34 80
Thu Dec 24 16:22:58 CET 2015 (46.12s ago)
```

Comment: This recipe displays age of process that created TCP connection, not connection itself.

Comment: @myroslav are you sure? It works against this [Node.js script](http://pastebin.com/m6Y14sxt).

Comment: I'd tested your new script with TCP connections opened by my Firefox on Fedora 22 64-bit, and I'm getting definitely not "uptime" numbers. When new socket opens, it is getting "random" uptime, usually the time of "youngest" ESTABLISHED socket.

Comment: @myroslav I'm using Debian (3.16.0-4-amd64) here, the only thing I notice is that the time reported is actually about 3 seconds late with respect to the socket creation. Maybe there are some system-dependent behaviors involved...

Comment: For the script, "$ suptime 192:168:120:10 6379
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
socket.error: illegal IP address string passed to inet_aton
Address does not match"

Comment: This works but it's not accurate: the `/proc/$pid/fd/$fd` entry is not created when the socket itself is created, but only on the first time this `/proc/$pid/fd` directory is being listed (testing on Linux 5.4.0). If you want it to be accurate you'd have to list the directory periodically.

Comment: @cYrus could you please add suptime6 for ipv6 and /proc/net/tcp6?

Comment: @VladislavKysliy I guess the only part that changes is the conversion from IPv6 to raw hex string, something like: `local hex_addr=$(python -c "import socket, struct; print(struct.pack('>IIII', *struct.unpack('@IIII', socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, '$addr'))).encode('hex').upper())")`

Comment: @Jong's comment makes sense for me. I have a process that has been running for months and has created several sockets. With this script, I obtain the same time for all of them: this morning, when I haved started to check them.

Answer (score 6):

This questions was helpful to me, but I found using `lsof` instead of `netstat` let me avoid all the HEX stuff:

For a process `${APP}` run by user `${USER}`, the following returns all the open sockets to the IP address ${IP}:

```
PEEID=$(sudo pgrep -u ${USER} ${APP}) && for i in `sudo lsof -anP -i -u logstash | grep ${IP} | awk '{print $6}'` ; do echo "${device} time" ; sudo find /proc/${PEEID}/fd -lname "socket:\[${device}\]" -printf %t 2> /dev/null  ; echo  ;  done
```

The `lsof` contains the `PID` too, but I am not sure how to get it and the device number.

This was tested on Amazon Linux.

Comment: Since `lsof` shows fd, you don't really need the `find` part but just check the fd time

Answer (score 3):

The script by cYrus worked for me but i had to fix it a bit (to get rid of a "L" in the hex address and to make port a 4 digit hex):

```
--- suptime.orig    2015-08-20 15:46:12.896652464 +0200
+++ suptime 2015-08-20 15:47:48.560074728 +0200
@@ -7,8 +7,8 @@
     hex_addr=$(python -c "
 import socket, struct;
 print hex(struct.unpack('<L',
-socket.inet_aton('$addr'))[0])[2:].upper().zfill(8)")
-    hex_port=$(python -c "print hex($port)[2:].upper()")
+socket.inet_aton('$addr'))[0])[2:10].upper().zfill(8)")
+    hex_port=$(python -c "print hex($port)[2:].upper().zfill(4)")
     inode=$(awk '$3 == "'$hex_addr:$hex_port'" {print $10}' /proc/net/tcp)
     time=$(find /proc/$pid/fd -lname "socket:\[$inode\]" -printf %A@)
     LANG=C printf '%.2fs' $(bc <<<"$(date +%s.%N) - $time")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> lsof -t -i @192.168.2.110 | xargs ps -fp

You can also tailor the "ps" command to just get pid and start time with -o such as:

> lsof -t -i @192.168.2.110 | xargs ps --no-headers -o'pid,start' -p

Of course this assumes the socket was started when the process was.

Comment: this shows how long the process that opened the socket is up. In case there is a process that runs all the time and there are network disconnects, these values would be very different. +1 for effort

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the script maintained in cYrus' answer. I had issues with it printing duplicates, probably because there may be many connections from different PIDs to the provided address, so here's my improved version that also prints the PID on each output line:

```
function suptime() {
    local addr=${1:?Specify the remote IPv4 address}
    local port=${2:?Specify the remote port number}

    # convert the provided address to hex format
    local hex_addr=$(python -c "import socket, struct; print(hex(struct.unpack('<L', socket.inet_aton('$addr'))[0])[2:10].upper().zfill(8))")
    local hex_port=$(python -c "print(hex($port)[2:].upper().zfill(4))")

    # get the inode of the socket
    local inodes=$(awk '$4 == "01" && $3 == "'$hex_addr:$hex_port'" {print $10}' /proc/net/tcp)
    [ -z "$inodes" ] && { echo 'Cannot lookup the socket(s)' 2>&1; return 1; }

    # get file descriptors
    for inode in $inodes; do
        # get inode's file descriptor details
        local fdinfo=( $(find /proc/[0-9]*/fd -lname "socket:\[$inode\]" -printf "%p %T@") )
        [ -z "$fdinfo" ] && { echo 'Cannot find file descriptor' 2>&1; return 1; }

        # extract pid
        local fdpath=${fdinfo[0]}
        local pid=${fdpath#/proc/}
        pid=${pid%%/*}

        # extract timestamp
        local timestamp=${fdinfo[1]}

        # compute the time difference
        LANG=C printf 'PID: %s; Age: %s (%.2fs ago)\n' "$pid" "$(date -d @$timestamp)" $(bc <<<"$(date +%s.%N) - $timestamp")
    done
}
```

Notes:

- needs `bc`, `netstat` (provided by `net-tools` on rhel >= 7 and similar systems)
- needs to be run as root

Answer (score 0):

A different version/form of [Raúl Cuza's script](https://superuser.com/a/1086937/399707), with some fixed bugs, that is (arguably) more usable, and which prints a total connections count:

```
APP=your-app
USER=user-app-runs-under
IP=ip-address-in-question
PID=$(sudo pgrep -u ${USER} ${APP})
CONNECTIONS=$(sudo lsof -anP -i -u ${USER} | grep ${IP} | awk '{print $6}')
echo "total ${USER} user connections to ${IP}: $(echo ${CONNECTIONS} | wc -w)"
for device in ${CONNECTIONS}; do
    timestamp=$(sudo find /proc/${PID}/fd -lname "socket:\[${device}\]" -printf %T@ 2> /dev/null);
    echo "${device} time";
    # compute the time difference
    LANG=C printf '%s (%.2fs ago)\n' "$(date -d @$timestamp)" $(bc <<<"$(date +%s.%N) - $timestamp");
    echo;
done
```